# Get average color of an image that comes from a url?

Tags: swift, uiimage

I'm trying to get the average color that's in an image and change the background to that color. (Kind of like how Instagram does it with their stories)

This is the extension I'm using to change the color:

```
extension UIImage {
var averageColor: UIColor? {
    guard let inputImage = CIImage(image: self) else { return nil }
    let extentVector = CIVector(x: inputImage.extent.origin.x, y: inputImage.extent.origin.y, z: inputImage.extent.size.width, w: inputImage.extent.size.height)
    
    guard let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAreaAverage", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: inputImage, kCIInputExtentKey: extentVector]) else { return nil }
    guard let outputImage = filter.outputImage else { return nil }
    
    var bitmap = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 4)
    let context = CIContext(options: [.workingColorSpace: kCFNull])
    context.render(outputImage, toBitmap: &bitmap, rowBytes: 4, bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1), format: .RGBA8, colorSpace: nil)
    
    return UIColor(red: CGFloat(bitmap[0]) / 255, green: CGFloat(bitmap[1]) / 255, blue: CGFloat(bitmap[2]) / 255, alpha: CGFloat(bitmap[3]) / 255)
}
```

}

The code I'm using to download an image from a url:

```
extension UIImageView {
func downloaded(from url: URL, contentMode mode: ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
    contentMode = mode
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard
            let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
            let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
            let data = data, error == nil,
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
        else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async() { [weak self] in
            self?.image = image
        }
    }.resume()
}
func downloaded(from link: String, contentMode mode: ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
    guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
    downloaded(from: url, contentMode: mode)
}
```

}

This is my tableview code for CellForRowAt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BookDetailsCell", for: indexPath) as! BookDetailsCell
       
            
var imageUrl = book!.volumeInfo.imageLinks?.thumbnail as! String 
let httpsRefactor = imageUrl.index(imageUrl.startIndex, offsetBy: 4) 
imageUrl.insert("s", at: httpsRefactor)      
cell.bookImage.downloaded(from: imageUrl)
            
            tableView.backgroundColor = cell.bookImage.image?.averageColor
            cell.bookBackgroundView.backgroundColor = cell.bookImage.image?.averageColor
            cell.rateButton.backgroundColor = cell.bookImage.image?.averageColor
            
      
        return cell
    }
```

When I try to set the color from the image view with `tableView.backgroundColor = cell.bookImage.image?.averageColor` it's  able to get the color from an image asset but not from the URL. How would I fix this?

Comment: You're not showing enough code to diagnose the issue for sure, but my guess is that you're trying to set the color before the image is downloaded. All I see in the completion handler for `URLSession.shared.dataTask` is `self?.image = image` -- how are you listening to that to trigger an update?

Comment: @jnpdx I have edited my question to include my tableView code that shows how I'm triggering the update

Comment: As I suspected, you aren't waiting for the download to complete before setting the background color. Unfortunately, I think your implementation will need some significant refactoring -- right now, you're downloading the image every time the cell loads, which is pretty inefficient. I'd suggest having a store/cache of the images and then triggering a tableView reload on the relevant cells when the data finishes downloading for any individual image.

Comment: @jnpdx ah, I see that now. I refactored the code the way you said and it is working perfectly now! Thank you.